# Given one solution, can a second solution always be found?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider a second order ODE:

$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=f(x)$$

A common procedure is to find linearly independent solutions $y_1,y_2$ to the homogenous ODE, and then apply the technique of [variation of parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters). I am wondering whether, given $y_1$, it is possible to find $y_2$.

**Thoughts:** we know that if $W$ is the [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) then practically by definition:$$y_2=y_1\int_{x_0}^x \frac{W(t)}{y_1^2(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t$$
So if we could find $W$ without knowing $y_2$, the problem is solved. Now we know $W$ satisfies $W'+p(x)W=0$. The problem is that the full solution to $Z'+p(x)Z=0$ will be "more than enough", since it does not involve $q(x)$, whereas $W$ should depend on $q(x)$.

Is there a condition (involving $q(x)$ and $y_1$) we can apply to a solution $Z$ of $Z'+p(x)Z=0$ so that we get $W?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume for example that $y_1(0) = 1, y_1'(0) = 0, y_2'(0) = 1$.
Then $W(0) = 1$ and the solution of the problem
$$
W' + pW = 0
\\
W(0) = 1
$$
is unique.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way of finding $y_2$ without any knowledge of it, so this does not quite cut it unfortunately.

Comment: there is not one solution, so there is no unique equation giving $y_2$. As simple as that. You can get it as soon as you know the initial value of the wronskian.

Comment: But surely given $p,q,y_1$ there can only be one $y_2?$ Or is that incorrect?

Comment: this is incorrect. there are infinitely many solutions that are linearly independant of $y_1$ (if the wronskian is non zero at any time it remains non zero)